# SharePoint Timer Service OWSTIMER.Exe taking more memory in sharepoint 2016 development server

Tags: 2013, 2016

Hi I have a SharePoint 2016 development server and below process is taking more memory in win 2016 server 
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\BIN\OWSTIMER.EXE

How can I troubleshoot why this SharePoint timer service is taking more memory, for SharePoint 2016 there is any SharePoint Dispose Checker Tool available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an application pool recycling issue .
I noticed the same in our SharePoint environments.
**Follow below steps**

Go to your IIS manager. You will see a Connections Pane.

Open the Connections pane and select the "Default App Pool".

In the "Actions" pane click on "Recycling" and schedule the recycling of app pool.

Run a IIS reset afterwards.

Whenever a app pool is recycled it restores several problems like Memory leak,application crashes etc.

The problem you are facing here is that of memory leak and hence it is necessary to schedule the app pool recycling.